# Access Derived class (forward declaration) using base class pointer

Tags: c++, googletest

How to access derived class member variable in my unit test framework(i.e. Gtest_main.cpp) from below scenario.

**imp.cpp**

```
   class base{
        public:
            virtual void foo()=0;
    };
    
    class derived : public base{
        public:
           int abc; // how to access this from Gtest_main.cpp
            void foo(){
                std::cout<<"This is derived foo() \n";
            }
    }; 

//Unit test framework call on createPlugin to get instance of derived class
  void createPlugin(base **plugin){
    derived *dp = new derived;
    *plugin=dp;
 }
```

**Gtest_main.cpp** (unit test file)

```
 class derived //forward declaration 
 base *p;
 createPlugin(&p);
 static_cast<derived*>(p)->abc=9090; //error how to access abc?
```

How to access **abc** in Gtest_main.cpp . Please note i can't modified the original source code impl.cpp

Comment: To be able to use the members of a class, you need the full definition of the class. Otherwise the compiler will simply not know what members the class actually have.

Comment: This might also be a good time to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), which us the unit the compiler actually works on.

Comment: Your `class derived;` (with ; missing) declaration is not enough. You have to include the class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to access `abc` in Gtest_main.cpp

You can't.  Without seeing the full definition of class `derived`, the compiler has no clue what `derived::abc` means.